# What parallelization issues will I run into?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm going to need to multi-thread the following code in python for homework (turned it into pseudocode). I just wanted to see if my solution is missing anything before I begin.

```
L = [2, 3, 4, ...]
sums = [0, 0, 0, ...]
for item in L:
     sums[hash(item)] += func(item)
```

My solution is to split the statement inside the for-loop: Save the 'item' variable in a temp variable, lock down L whenever I do this, and then calculate the information hash(temp_item) and func(temp_item) into more temp variables. Then lock down L and update it.

Is this the best solution? Only locking the variables when I'm taking or updating.

This more about learning parallelism properly than the limitations of python.

Comment: L is an integer array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems you'll encounter depend on how you implement your threading.

The big one:

- Python doesn't do threads like you expect due to the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). This lock must be acquired any time any Python object is modified. Therefore **Python threads cannot make your code faster because all the threads are practically serialized by the GIL**. They're only useful for things like I/O or GUI drawing. If you want threads for performance look into [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) which is something related but different.

Let's pretend, though:

- If you lock on `sums` then any time you do any sort of modification to any element then you'll essentially serialize all the threads and you won't see any parallelism.
- Doing a lock inside the loop means that the lock itself maybe be more expensive than the computation. You might not see the parallel code gain anything. This is only worthwhile if `func` is very expensive.
- You do NOT need to lock `L` because you only read from it. Multiple threads can read the same block of memory safely. Only writes are dangerous.

So I basically told you that you need to lock `sums` somehow but you can't because every method is slow. What's done for performance is for each thread to have its own `sums` while it's working, then when the threads finish you combine all the threads' copies back into a single `sum`.

Comment: "Python doesn't have real threads due to the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)." This is **false**. Python uses **real OS threads**. The fact that the interpreter doesn't allow them to *execute bytecode* at the same time is *not* the same as saying they aren't "real threads". If you use libraries written in C you can often release the GIL thus allowing true parallelism (e.g. `numpy` does this all the time when it can).

Comment: True. It's quite often that to get performance from Python you need to not use Python. However, in pure Python code the GIL kills any performance benefits from threads so in they're practically useless for performance. If threaded code doesn't behave like threaded code is expected to, to me that doesn't look like true threads.

Comment: To keep track of the changes made to sum, I would probably use another list but at that point am I not serializing the code again?

Comment: I'll rephrase for pedantic reasons

Comment: two lists won't change anything. you need a second list *for every thread*. That helps because you don't need to lock those per-thread lists. You then only lock `sums` once when you join all the threads.

Comment: It's also possible to do the join in a threaded way as well so the critical path is `log(T)` joins

Comment: If each thread has a list, what's stopping them from going over an item multiple times?

Comment: Each thread has its own `sums`. You're iterating over `L`. You said you'd split that up evenly.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Give each thread a portion of the sums list.

Comment: But seriously, unless this is practice, homework or a thought exercise, don't even bother with Python threads for this. It's impossible to get better performance.